# Reloading searchResultsTableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have, in my main tableView, some custom cells (cells with an imageView, basically).

The imageView is set only if a value on my plist is false. Then, when it's true, the imageView is nil.

Basically when the user enters the detailView, the value is set to `YES` and the `cell.imageView` is nil.

And it's okay, it works

I'm using a `searchDisplayController`, when i search for something that has a cell.imageView, going into the detailView and then coming back to the `searchResultsTable`, the cell has still the image, while it shouldn't, but the main tableView has the correct cell (so, with no image).

I thought that it could depend on searchResultsTableView, but i'm not sure. 
I tried with

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
```

with no effect.

How could i reload the searchResultsTableView so that it shows the right cells, those with the image and those that don't have the image anymore?

Any help appreciated!

*EDIT*

This is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    NSArray *rows;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        rows = filteredList; //for search
    } else {
        NSDictionary *section = [localSortedTips objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        rows = [section objectForKey:@"Rows"];
    }

    NSDictionary *item = [rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"name"];  
    if ([[item valueForKey:@"isRead"] boolValue] == NO) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unread.png"];
    } else {
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
    }
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
    cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: are you saying that a particular cell will have a photo before you go to the detail view, but will not have the picture after you come back?  it looks to me like you are caching your filteredResults value, and if you are changing the data behind the scenes, my guess is that the filteredResults are not also being updated.

Comment: Basically when i come back to the view the image should be updated, but it only works when deleting the search word and search back again

Comment: so, as i said ... it looks from the code snippet like you are caching your filteredResults.  given that it sounds like you are changing what would be in the contents of those results behind the scenes, you either need to do the search again (as you suggested), or when you update something in the detail view, you need to update the cached filteredResults as well as the other results.  or you need to change what the contents of filteredResults contains so its' items are not copies of the things you are changing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood you right, then you can have a workaround but searching again with the same search string:

```
if (self.searchDisplayController.active) {
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text;
}
```

put it in `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` which will be called each time the view is shown up (eg. you go back from the `detail view` to your `search view`). And reloading the data in this place would be nice too, to get the right data (for example if you marked the cell as read like in your sample code)

Just `[self.tableView reloadData];` and not the `searchResultsTableView` (it will be automatically use the updated data after the new search)

Comment: Amazing work! The images now are being showed (and not showed) correctly! Finally, banged my head against the wall for the past days!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if perhaps your cells are being recycled and not reset properly. UITableView uses view recycling, so it's important that if you do something such as set an image you make sure it is explicitly set even when their isn't an image to display.

If you share your `cellsForRowAtIndexPath` code you might be able to get some more help.