# TableView Search Controller Accessory View does not Update

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've built a simple tableview with an accessory view for each row. 
I've added a uisearchcontroller. Everytime I search for an object and then select the accessory view for this object the accessory view image does not update.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;
UIImage *Image;
Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];
[button setBackgroundImage:Image forState:UIControlStateNormal]; }
```

After I cancel the search the checkmarks are visible (accessory view) for the rows I searched for.

Comment: Is that your whole tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:? Where is the cell variable defined?

Comment: `if (self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text.length > 0) {
        
        stringxyz = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
       stringxyz =  [self.someArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    
    
    NSIndexPath *indexValue = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.someArray indexOfObject:stringxyz] inSection:0];
    
 UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexValue];`

Comment: Solution found. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352403/reloading-searchresultstableview

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cell of resultTableView of UISearchController, try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
         cell=[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    else
         cell=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;
    UIImage *Image;
    Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];
    [button setBackgroundImage:Image forState:UIControlStateNormal]; }
```

Comment: Does not work for me :( Accessory View is still unchanged in searchResultsTableView

Comment: maybe I need something to refresh the search results?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me! Thanks to user207616

```
if (self.searchDisplayController.active) {
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text; }
```